# Why is it showing different output in BigDecimal?

Tags: java, bigdecimal

I tried to divided the floating point number. Finally I found the `BigDecimal` class, and initialized the floating point number. However it was different what I expected.

```
BigDecimal d1 = new BigDecimal(0.6883116883116883116883116883);
System.out.println(d1);
```

I expect the output will be `0.6883116883116883116883116883`

but the console's output was
`0.68831168831168831889755210795556195080280303955078125`.

Comment: The double literal has already lost precision by the time it is passed to the constructor. Use the string constructor, e.g. `new BigDecimal("0.688311...")`

Comment: I tried `BigDecimal d1 = BigDecimal.valueOf(0.6883116883116883116883116883);` but it`s output was `0.6883116883116883`.. Thanks your reply. I'll try it.